# How to setup auto backup on a heroku pg follower?

Tags: heroku, backup

From pgbackups documentation:

Note that capturing a backup does add some load on your database for the duration of the backup. How this impacts your application will vary with the size of your database and the nature of the app. Consider taking backups on a follower if there is a significant impact from running them on the master.

I know I can create a manual backup using the command `heroku pgbackups:capture FOLLOWER_DATABASE_URL`

But when I add the pgbackups addon through the website https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups it comes with autoback that I don't know how to turn off.  When installing the addon, it asks me which app to add it to, but not which database.  I have no idea when the automatic backup will run, nor do I know which database it will run on, the primary or the follower.

Answer (score 0):

The autobackup will run on the primary database -- you can only capture backups on a follower manually.